# GoJS set layout from bottom to top, and drop nodes on top

Tags: javascript, gojs

I want to have two groups which have vertical layout in a diagram, each group have some nodes which can be dragged and dropped into another group, and i want to drop the node on the top of the group.

this is what i want:

[beforedrop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LVLr.jpg)

[afterdrop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlTSx.jpg)

I searched gojs api and tried to use go.LayeredDigraphLayout, [gojs LayeredDigraphLayout](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/LayeredDigraphLayout.html), the api said set the direction to 270 is upwards, but seems not work..

my nodes still layout from top to bottom, and when i drop the node, it moves to the bottom...

this is what i got:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etcUv.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89jz2.png)

here is my code:

```js
function init() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates

    myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
      {
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        layout: $(go.GridLayout, { wrappingColumn: 2 }),
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true
      });

    myDiagram.groupTemplateMap.add("Group",
      $(go.Group, "Auto",
        {   resizable:  false,
            computesBoundsAfterDrag: true,
            layout: $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout,
                { columnSpacing: 5, direction: 180}),
            mouseDrop: function(e, grp) {
                    grp.addMembers(grp.diagram.selection, true);
            },
        },
        $(go.Shape, { fill: "white", stroke: "lightgray",width:200 }),
        $(go.Placeholder, { padding: 10 })
      ));

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        {
            mouseDrop: function(e, grp) {
                grp.diagram.currentTool.doCancel();
            }
        },
        $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 3 },
          new go.Binding("text", "key"))
      );
    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
    [
      { key: "G1", isGroup: true, category: "Group" },
      { key: "G2", isGroup: true, category: "Group" },
      { key: "Alpha", color: "lightblue", group: "G1" },
      { key: "Beta", color: "orange", group: "G1" },
      { key: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen", group: "G1" },
      { key: "Delta", color: "pink", group: "G1" },
      { key: "Alpha2", color: "lightblue", group: "G2" },
      { key: "Beta2", color: "orange", group: "G2" },
      { key: "Gamma2", color: "lightgreen", group: "G2" },
      { key: "Delta2", color: "pink", group: "G2" }
    ]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/release/go.js"></script>
<body onload="init()">
<div id="myDiagramDiv" style="flex-grow: 1; height: 500px; border: solid 1px black"></div>
</body>
```

i put the code on git, just a html: [GoJS_Layout_git](https://github.com/saint37/GoJS_Layout)

can anyone help me with this problem? many thanks

Comment: thanks to Walter Northwoods! finally i used go.GridLayout, set wrappingColumn to 1, and set its comparer. Now problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make each **Group.layout** sort the nodes in the order that you want.  **LayeredDigraphLayout** won't help you there, since it is supposed to re-order the nodes in a layer to reduce link crossings.

Instead, use **GridLayout** or **TreeLayout** and set their respective **sorting** and **comparer** properties.  The latter must be a function that compares two **Node**s (when GridLayout) or two **LayoutVertex**es (when TreeLayout) for sorting purposes.  There are examples of this in the documentation, such as at https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/TreeLayout.html#comparer